# Can you have git run code after a merge, like you can with composer after dump-autoload?

Tags: git, githooks

I am hoping to be able to fetch some code and then merge it with git, and once the git command has merged fire off another command.

In my case I am using PHP and Laravel with the response cache package from spatie.
I am wanting to do the `git fetch` and then `git merge`, as I usually do, and then it automatically run the `php artisan responsecache:clear` command.  I want this as I often forget about it and get really confused when I don't see my changes come in.

Is this possible with git?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks, https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks, https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_merge

Comment: cool, thanks @phd, i shall take a look